# how to solve the error on service request and timer

Tags: c#

```
 private static void TranslateMethod(string authToken)
        {
            // Add TranslatorService as a service reference, Address:http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc
            TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient client = new TranslatorService.LanguageServiceClient();//error occur here
...
accessTokenRenewer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(OnTokenExpiredCallback), this, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(RefreshTokenDuration), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));//error occur here also
```

///
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'TranslatorService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\user-pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 62 13 WindowsFormsApplication1

Error 2 The type or namespace name 'TranslatorService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\user-pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 62 66 WindowsFormsApplication1

Error 3 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer' C:\Users\user-pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 101 17 WindowsFormsApplication1

Error 4 'Timer' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' and 'System.Threading.Timer' C:\Users\user-pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 112 38 WindowsFormsApplication1

Error 5 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' does not contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments C:\Users\user-pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 112 34 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: full coding at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512437.aspx, I want to try it out but it cannot work. Hope someone can tell me solution for the error occur. Thank.

Comment: Please describe your question in body

Comment: `Add TranslatorService as a service reference` did you do that? and what is the error?

Comment: the error detected using visual basic was The type or namespace name 'TranslatorService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\user-pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 62 13 WindowsFormsApplication1

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;

Comment: Please edit your question to include all of this info, instead of putting it in comments. Thanks!